# Is there any callback for when downloading via setting an Anchor Tags a.download property and then executing a.click()?

Tags: javascript, html

Using the following code, I am forcing an image to be downloaded:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = randomImageForSpotCheck;
a.download = randomImageForSpotCheck.split("/")[randomImageForSpotCheck.split("/").length-1]; // Filename only
a.click();
```

Is there any callback available to be notified when download complete or a way to access the file?